# Nesting Batch For Do loops to work with folder name and filename

Tags: string, for-loop, batch-file

I would like to recursively execute a command in a loop, to set a metadadata tag on files based on the folder name (which is a date) for files in a tree structure.
Basically something like

`FOR /R [folder] %%G in (*.mts) DO Exiftool -DateCreated=[folder name of]%%G %%G`

However, I see no way to extract the folder name of the parameter - `%%~pG` will give me the entire path - including slashes

Thus I thought of nesting loops like this:

```
FOR /d /r  %%G IN (.) DO (
     FOR %%H IN (*.mts)  DO (
           echo %%~nG %%~nH
     )     
)
```

`%%~nG` will report the folder name but `%%H`  is not available - the output looks like this:
`(FOR %H IN (*.mts) DO (echo 2017-11-12 %~nH ) )` 
Maybe the second for-loop does not know where to start - how do I tell it so?

Comment: `for /R [folder] %%G in (*.mts) do for %%H in ("%%~pG.") do echo File: "%%~nxG"; Parent: "%%~nxH"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 FOR %%H IN (*.mts)  DO (
```

will look for `.mts` files in the current directory.

You want to look in the current `%%G` directory, so use

```
 FOR %%H IN ("%%G\*.mts")  DO (
```

Comment: Thanks! - exactly what I needed.